# Rendering diagrams in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am having a really hard time getting diagrams to render in QGIS 3.0. I have 5 points with 7 parameter values associated with each that I would like to depict as a histogram. I don't have "simplify geometry" selected under rendering options.

Could it be a problem with my field types?

[image]

Comment: What are your field types?Try converting to numerical field types if they're not already.